# Javascript: Implementing modulus where remainder 0 yields divisor instead

Tags: javascript, math

In my current project, I've often needed to know the position of a number within a given interval (and it needed to be 1-based, not 0 based). Let's use converting time as an example -- going from the 0-based 24 hour clock to the 1-based 12 hour clock (so 12 is the interval). Given 2 hrs or 14 hrs, the 'position' should be 2. Given 0 or 12, the position equals 12 (not 0).

The obvious method is modulo -- `14 % 12 = 2` as expected. However, `12 % 12 = 0`, and like I said, it needs to be 1-based. I couldn't just add 1 to the result of the modulo to make it 1-based, because then the position of 12 in the interval 12 would be 1, the position of 14 in 12 would be 3, and so on.

I came up with 2 methods to solve this:

1. `position = value % interval || interval` (relying on the falsey 0)
2. `position = (value - 1) % interval + 1` (or if you need to support values that start at 0, like in the 24-hour clock, it would be `(value + interval - 1)` instead)

Which of these methods should be used?
Are there pros / cons / potential pitfalls I should be aware of?
Or is there a better method that I'm unaware of?

Comment: For converting time, you really should be using the [**`Date`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/date-object-javascript) object. [**Here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/calculating-dates-and-times-javascript) is the relevant documentation for calculations with the Date object.

Comment: I'd say `(value + 11) % 12 + 1` to deal with JS' *remainder* (not modulus) operator behaviour, but yes pretty much the second one.

Comment: `position = value % interval || interval` is completely ok (and by far the most readable method), if you know you're dealing with numbers all the time. If you're not sure, you should check that `value` is a number in any method. Any other pros/cons are math related and not JS related.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: I'm not actually converting time. It was a convenient and relatable example. :)  I'm going to edit my question to remove the HH:MM notation, and just use integer hours, so maybe other people won't think that as well.

Comment: @Bergi: Would you care to elaborate on why you'd recommend the latter to the former? Possible answer material!  :)

Comment: @MarcusHughes Because `-1 % 12 = -1` (not 11 as one might expect), so you'd have the 0 again. Or is that what you referred to in the parenthesis already?

Comment: Ah. In my project, I was dealing with 0-based ranges, but it was guaranteed that they'd never be a negative number (0 was the lowest possible value), so I never thought of that ramification for the other one. So given that context, neither method is necessarily more advantageous in your estimation?

Comment: the question seems opinion based, because the first one seems more readable (and I personally prefer it), but `(value + 11) % 12 + 1` is a bit more "correct" if there is even a tiny chance for the number to not be integer. As a side note, the first one seems a tiny bit slower, because the possible branch misprediction from `||`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping not to get 'preference' responses, and more things along the lines of the possible performance difference you mentioned, or whether one is more robust in always returning the correct answer. Given both of the things you said, it would seem the second method is the better. I was honestly hoping there was some native method I was unaware of!

Answer (score 0):

So based on the comments I received, both methods I originally came up with were lacking in type checking and in how they handled zeros or negatives. Based on that feedback, I changed my function to the following:

```
function positionInInterval( value, interval ) {

    // Check for valid input
    // Rather than throw an error, you could return undefined or NaN
    if ( typeof value !== 'number' || typeof interval !== 'number' )
        throw new TypeError('Argument type must be Number');
    if ( interval < 2 )
        throw new RangeError('Interval must be greater than 1');

    if ( value < 0 )
        return value % interval + interval;

    return value % interval || interval;
}
```

It treats all numbers as being on a continuous 'number line', including negative numbers, so that by increasing `value` by 1, its 'position' in `interval` always increases by 1, until the next interval.

<sup>**Note:** user Slai indicated that `||` might make Method 1 slightly slower than Method 2, but at least in Chrome, they seemed neck and neck, *except* when I determined `value` with `Math.random()`, in which case `||` was always slightly faster.</sup>

---

I know the use cases related to this question are limited, but I hope it helps someone out! This is the sort of information that I never know I need until I stumble across it.  :)